# Windows XP for an Android develepmont environment

Tags: java, android, windows, development-environment

**Clarification:**
My previous Android development environment has been a Win7 machine using command-line build tools with the MinGW bash shell that is installed with Git. I am trying to create a similar environment on an ancient WinXP machine.

**Original Question:**

I am setting up an old Windows XP machine for my Android development environment. (Yah, I know I wish I had the means to buy a new Win7 -- or better yet Win8 -- machine. I am making do with what I have for the moment.) My current problem is that when I run my `ant -f build-android.xml debug` I get the following error:

```
-dex:
      [dex] Found Deleted Target File
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into c:\devel\src\java\bbct\bin\classes.dex...
       [dx] ************ java_exe=
       [dx] The system cannot find the path specified.
       [dx]
       [dx] ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
       [dx] Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
       [dx] We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
       [dx]   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads
       [dx]
       [dx] You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
       [dx]   http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html
       [dx]
```

With a little detective work, I figured out that the `-dex` target runs `${android.platform.tools.dir}/dx${bat}` which in turn runs `..\tools\lib\find_java.bat` part of which is as follows:

```
rem Useful links:
rem Command-line reference:
rem   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx

rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path. The return code will
rem be 0 if the command worked or 1 if the exec failed (program not found).
for /f %%a in ('%~dps0\find_java.exe -s') do set java_exe=%%a
if not defined java_exe goto :CheckFailed
```

Running `find_java.exe -s` from the command-line gives

```
c:/PROGRA~1/Java/JDK16~1.0_3\bin\java.exe
```

which is the correct location of my JDK installation. However, when I add an echo statement between the `for` and `if` commands in the above batch script snippet, I can see that the `java_exe` variable is not set or is empty. I have successfully compiled my Android apps on a Win7 machine, so I believe the problem is that the `for` command above is incorrect for a WinXP environment. How do I change it in order to get it to work in WinXP? If the problem isn't specific to WinXP, then what is wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: I know this isn't a direct solution, but if you're running XP because of a lack of license for Win7 or 8, why not just run Ubuntu? I think it's much friendlier for Android development.

Comment: @dennisdrew I'm considering running some flavor of Linux. The biggest issue is that this machine doesn't have an Internet connection, so I'm installing things off my USB atm.  I'm not sure how well that will work for Linux...

Comment: @Code-Guru : I run XP but I use Eclipse for Android development. I know that doesn't answer your question but after a fairly easy setup, there's no need to run command-line tools or batch files.

Comment: @Squonk Even if I decide to go with Eclipse, I'd still like to know what the problem is with my current set-up.

Comment: @Code-Guru : I understand that. My only point was simply because I prefer an IDE - I've worked with scripts and batch files for a very long time and often found using them in a development environment they can prove more hassle than they're worth. Eclipse isn't perfect but I prefer a way of 'visually' setting up my IDE rather than editing scripts and batch files. As I said, it doesn't answer your specific problem but it's a good alternative to get things working for you IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

The short answer is that I think I found a bug in the WinXP command-line interpreter. At the very least, the behavior in Win7 differs from that of WinXP. I start with discussing and breaking down the cause of the problem. I will finish with a proposed fix to the `find_java.bat` script that comes with the Android SDK.

**Long Answer:**

The offending line is in fact the for loop from the `find_java.bat` script:

```
for /f %%a in ('%~dps0\find_java.exe -s') do set java_exe=%%a
```

According to the [MS docs](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true), the syntax that applies here is for a for loop used to iterate over file names:

```
for /F ["ParsingKeywords"] {%% | %}variable in (filenameset) do command [CommandLineOptions]
```

Let's break this down:

- We are not using the the `"ParsingKeywords"`
- If this command is used in a batch script, then we need `%%` in front of the variable name. If we run it from the command-line, then only a single `%` is used.
- In our situation, `'%~dps0\find_java.exe -s'` describes the "filenameset". This *should* evaluate to the output of running `find_java.exe -s`.

  - Running `find_java.exe` manually from the MinGW command-line on my WinXP machine gives correct output.
  - Next I modified the `find_java.bat` file as follows:

    - `rem`'d out the `@echo off` command at the beginning. (This wasn't shown in the OP.) This prints out each of the commands from the batch file as they execute.
    - Added an echo command to see the value of `java_exe`

    To run the modified `find_java.bat` file directly, I used the native WinXP `cmd` command-line. (I should also try this using the ant script in MinGW.) The relevant output was

    ```
    C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib>for /F %a in ('C:\PROGRA~1\ANDROID\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\FIND_J~1\find_java.exe -s') do set java_exe=%a
    The system cannot find the path specified.

    C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib>echo ************ java_exe=
    ************ java_exe=
    ```

    As you can see, `java_exe` is empty. I also found the path `C:\PROGRA~1\ANDROID\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\FIND_J~1\find_java.exe` a little bit strange; it should be `C:\PROGRA~1\ANDROID\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\find_java.exe`, instead. Further investigation shed some light on what is happening:

    - %0, %1, %2, etc. refer to the command-line arguments
    - The syntax %~[modifiers][#] provides some additional arguments about how to deal with the command-line argument. In particular, the values of the `modifiers` here include

      - d = Expand the drive letter
      - p = Expand the path name
      - s = Expand using short 8.3 DOS names

      The idea is that we want to run the `find_java.exe` executable which is in the same directory as the `find_java.bat` script where this code is located. `%0` refers to the name of the batch script. Now for some reason, the WinXP command-line interpreter includes the batch script's file name in this expansion, rather than just expanding the path where it is located. Since the path is incorrect, `find_java.exe` never executes and the `java_exe` variable is never set to a valid value. On the other hand, Win7 expands just the path of the batch script and everything runs just fine.
  - The `command` sets the value of the `java_exe` variable which is used later in another script.

**Solution:**
When I remove the `s` modifier from `'%~dps0\find_java.exe -s'` gives the path of the executing batch file without the file name. However, now there are possibly spaces and other special characters in the path. To fix this, I simply add double-quotes in appropriate places. The final for command looks like this:

```
for /f %%a in ('"%~dp0\find_java.exe" -s') do set java_exe=%%a
```

Since the behavior changes when removing the `s` modifier, I believe there is a bug in the WinXP command-line interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Add c:/PROGRA~1/Java/JDK16~1.0_3\bin\ to Path environment variable

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This directory is already in the PATH variable since running `find_java.exe -s` by hand gives the expected output. However, running this same command (embedded in the for loop give in the bash script as shown in the OP) doesn't give the same output.